# Saving Existing Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

How do I save an [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) workbook using [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to save after you manually changed something with your code, you could simply use `ThisWorkbook.Save`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this to save the current workbook or even create a new one on a different location

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=file_name
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

Comment: Uhm, I think it's not a good idea to close the window you're workin with ;)

Comment: you are right  I do it often when creating new data but the OP didnt ask for it so I edited it, thanks for pointing that out!